# Syntax for a Complex Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I need help with a formula that will return true only when

( category <> "red" )

OR

( category = "red" AND EmployeeName  is not empty )

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(category <> "red",TRUE,if(EmployeeName<>""))`
or
`=IF(category <> "red",TRUE,not(isblank(EmployeeName)))`

**ALSO**, since the result ill be `FALSE` ONLY when EmployeeName is null and category is red you could just do:
`=NOT(AND(EmployeeName="",category="red"))`